# How to allow popup to open when yes button is pressed from Ext.Msg.confirm?

Tags: javascript, button, popup, dom-events, sencha-touch-2

I need my application to be able to open a popup when the yes button is pressed from the prompt. I have tried this and it doesn't work:

```
Ext.Msg.confirm(
    "Press for popup",
    "Do you want to proceed?",
    function(buttonId) {
        if (buttonId === 'yes') {
            window.open("http://www.w3schools.com");//Chrome says it has blocked a popup
        }
    }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need change Chrome settings to de-block popup windows.

Comment: But shouldn't direct user event be able to open popup when using default settings?